# Export synthetic dataset created with sklearn to csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scikit-learn

I need to create a synthetic dataset, cause i have to fix a clustering algorithm for my university thesis, so i need it to test the algorithm with a little dataset.
I managed to create it with sklearn make_classification, but the program takes in input a csv file that contains the features of the dataset.
Does anyone know how can i manage to create a synthetic dataset directly in csv, or export the one created with sklearn into a csv file?

Comment: use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Comment: I saw the docs, but i can't understand how can i use it for my purpose

Comment: If your synthetic dataset is a numpy array you can use `numpy.savetxt` to export it to a csv file.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a numpy array to a csv file using `numpy.savetxt`.

This example uses a `BytesIO` instance as output, you would use a file name instead.

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.random.randn(5, 2)

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
array([[-0.13114465, -0.72491874],
       [-0.08375738, -1.23769691],
       [-0.5583027 , -0.24086865],
       [ 0.04590227, -0.6582806 ],
       [-0.21433652, -0.78924272]])

In [5]: buf = io.BytesIO()

In [6]: np.savetxt(buf, x, delimiter=',')

In [7]: print(buf.getvalue().decode())
-1.311446488105691699e-01,-7.249187409818331762e-01
-8.375738326459475358e-02,-1.237696910731503452e+00
-5.583026953882282983e-01,-2.408686450946319058e-01
4.590226685041418758e-02,-6.582805971999975414e-01
-2.143365241670896482e-01,-7.892427231682124233e-01
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but the result it's a csv file with an array value in each row, separated by a comma, is there any way to put values separated by a comma into different columns in the csv file?

Comment: @IlarioSalatino No idea what you mean. In my code I have an array with two columns, so the exported csv has two columns. That's not a value in each row but two values in each row. If that's not what you want then add a [mcve] to your question.